# How to sort a NSMutableArray using NSSortDescriptor?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I'm parsing data from `JSON` webservice and then using the following code to sort the data by price, date, discount etc.

here's the code I'm using to sort the data:

```
-(void)priceSort:(id)sender {

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                     initWithKey: @"price" ascending: YES];

NSMutableArray *sortedArray = (NSMutableArray *)[self.displayItems
                                          sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

[self setDisplayItems:sortedArray];

[self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

this works fine when I'm trying to sort by price, however when I want to sort by number of reviews I can't seem to get the code right:

for price I use:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                         initWithKey: @"price" ascending: YES];
```

but for reviews I want to get the "n" value. see how it's nested in the output (of the display Items mutableArray below:

```
"old_price" = 24;
        price = "9.9";
        reviews =         {
            **n = 11;**
            val = 70;
        };
        "sold_count" = 101;
```

thanks for any help on this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sort by the number of reviews `n`, your sort descriptor would be:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                     initWithKey: @"reviews.n" ascending: YES];
```